# Create matrix containing values in [0,1] where sum of all diagonals and anti-diagonals is fixed

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, graph-theory, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

The problem I am facing sounds at first glance pretty simple. However, as very often, it seems more complicated than I first assumed:

I want to calculate a matrix $P = (p_{j,k}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, satisfying the following constraints:

1. $p_{j,k} \in [0,1]$,
2. $\sum_{j,k} \ p_{j,k} = 1$,
3. the sums of all $2n-1$ diagonals are fixed by $b_{1-n},\ldots,b_{n-1}\in (0,1)$, e.g. $\sum_{j} p_{j,j} = b_0$ or $\sum_{j} p_{j,j+1} = b_{-1}$, and finally
4. the sums of all $2n-1$ antidiagonals are fixed by $a_1,\ldots,a_{2n-1}\in (0,1)$.

Obviously, the problem is easy to solve for $n=2$, since the "corner elements" of the matrix are directly given from 3. and 4. However, for $n>2$, it becomes more difficult.

A simple linear algebra approach for $n=3$ leads to the problem of "solving" $Mp=c$ with 
$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
1 &  &  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
& 1 & & 1 & & & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  
& & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & & & 1 & & 1 & \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & &\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & & & & 1 & \\ 
1 & & & & 1 & & & & 1\\
& 1 & & & & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  
&  &  1 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
1& 1 & 1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad p = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
p_{1,1} \\ 
p_{1,2} \\
p_{1,3} \\ 
p_{2,1} \\
p_{2,2} \\ 
p_{2,3} \\
p_{3,1} \\ 
p_{3,2} \\
p_{3,3}
\end{array} \right), \quad c = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
a_4 \\
a_5 \\
b_{-2} \\
b_{-1} \\
b_{0} \\
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
1
\end{array} \right) 
$$
where $p \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{4n-1}$ and $M$ is of size $(4n-1)\times n^2$ with entries in $\{0,1\}$. Note that $M$ is rank-deficient and the rows that specify the values for the "corner elements" are clearly visible. Dropping these rows leaves
$$
\tilde{M} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
& 1 & & 1 & & & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  
& & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & & & 1 & & 1 & \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & & & & 1 & \\ 
1 & & & & 1 & & & & 1\\
& 1 & & & & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  
1& 1 & 1&1 &1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  
\end{array}
\right), \quad \tilde{p} = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
p_{1,2} \\
p_{2,1} \\
p_{2,2} \\ 
p_{2,3} \\
p_{3,2} \\
\end{array} \right), \quad \tilde{c} = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{c} 
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
a_4 \\
b_{-1} \\
b_{0} \\
b_{1} \\
1-a_1-a_5-b_{-2}-b_2
\end{array} \right) .
$$
The question is, if there exists a solution (for $n \in \mathbb{N}$) for this problem satisfying all properties and how to calculate it (least-squares, SVD,...)? Or is there an approach different from the one I chose which is suitable to compute a solution iteratively? I have the intuition, that due to the somewhat special constraints, there is a close connection to probability ("values are positive, sum equals one") or graph (adjacency matrices) theory.

Comment: If $n\in\{2,3\}$, you have more conditions than unknowns, so if the $a$s and $b$s don't satisfy some kind of a consistency condition, there is no solution. If $n=2$, then $a_{\pm1}$ and $b_{\pm1}$ determine the matrix uniquely and easily, but that matrix may not satisfy the other conditions.

Comment: Yep, that's true, I know. And I suspect that it will crash at that point. I already thought about defining a multivariate function and applying BOBYQA in order to minimize it under the given constraints. However, I am still interested in similar problems with known solutions.

Comment: If you have a solution you can choose two diagonals and two antidiagonals which intersect each other in four points, add a value to two of them and substract the same value to the other. The result is then again a solution. Maybe you can even build a new basis like this which makes the linear system easier.

Comment: These conditions are always dependent, and not only due to the sum of all elements. E.g., the sum of all elements with the even sum of indices can be expressed both via $a_i$ and via $b_i$.

Comment: Choose all entries not on the main diagonal or main antidiagonal with random numbers. If the $a_i$ and $b_i$ satisfy the compatibility condition mentioned by Ilya Bogdanov you can complete this matrix such that it satisfies 2., 3. and 4. To get condition 1. you can use the idea of the comment of user35593.

Answer (score 1):

The given constraints are a system of linear inequalities, so you can find a feasible solution (or prove that none exists) by feeding these constraints to a linear program (LP) solver with some arbitrarily chosen objective function.